# How to install memcache extension (php72, macos Catalina)

Tags: macos, memcached, php-7.2, macos-catalina

I can't install memcache (not memcached) extension on MacOs Catalina, php 7.2

```
checking for the location of zlib... configure: error: memcache support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcache/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php-config --enable-memcache-session=yes' failed
```

I try

```
pecl install memcache --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include/zlib.h
```

But

```
Attempting to discover channel "--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include"...
unknown channel "--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include" in "--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include/zlib.h"
invalid package name/package file "--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include/zlib.h"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close... Your path should not to be the header file but to the directory. Also, pecl install doesn't pass the command line parameter in the script down to the ./configure command so you have to do it yourself:

```
pecl download memcache
open memcache-4.0.5.2.tgz  
cd memcache-4.0.5.2/memcache-4.0.5.2
phpize
./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: If you need to rebuild, be sure to cleanup before re-running phpize:

`rm -fr build run-tests.php`

otherwise you're likely to get "permission denied" error because the files are set read-only at the end of the make && make install.

Answer (score 4):

You can use env variable `PHP_ZLIB_DIR` to tell it where zlib is.

```
PHP_ZLIB_DIR=/usr/local/opt/zlib pecl install memcache
```

Comment: And for MacPorts' zlib this directory is "/opt/local"

Comment: Thank you!
In my case I had to do `PHP_ZLIB_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib pecl install memcache-4.0.5.2` as I installed zlib using brew